# Dapr dotnet-sdk pubsub tried to use a consumer group that was closed

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, dapr

I'm using Dapr for sending and receiving messages from kafka with .net. I have an multiple controller for multiple topics. When starting application in kubernates then it has bellow error. If dapr subscribe single topic, then everything is ok but multiple topic subscriptions has an exception has occured. How can I solve this issue? Any suggestion for this?

```
level=info msg="app is subscribed to the following topics: [Topic1 Topic 2] through pubsub=........."

level=error msg="Error consuming [Topic1]. Retrying...: kafka: tried to use a consumer group that was closed"
```

**Contoller 1:**

```
public class Topic1Controller : ControllerBase
{

   [Topic("pubsub-name", "Topic1")]
   public Task HandleAsync(Topic1Event @event)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
 }
```

**Controller 2:**

```
public class Topic2Controller : ControllerBase
{
  [Topic("pubsub-name", "Topic2")]
  public Task HandleAsync(Topic2Event @event)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
 }
```